# Creating a dynamically-sized multidimensional list in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to build a multi-dimensional list in Python where the number of the dimensions isn't known at the time of writing (development-time) but determined dynamically at runtime.

Example: If I want to create a n-dimensional lattice where each lattice point corresponds to a object I created. 
Here i want to know the algorithm for varying n while the program runs.

Comment: For SOme reason i was not able to add this in the question,
ie, i want the code to create this when n = 2
>        [[,..,],..,[,..,]]
and this when n = 3,
>       [[[,..,],..,[,..,]],.....,[[,..,],..,[,..,]]]

Comment: Please show an extended example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, how is this used in your program/app?

Comment: This is not helping us in finding a solution. What kind of data do you want to have in the array? Is the array with n=2 just [[...],[...]] or is it of variable length? Is it used for a mathematical problem? How you want to use this? You might want to read the guide for asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Editing for legibility

Answer (score 0):

Pure Python Solution:

```
n = 2
f = [[0.0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)]
f[0][0] = 8
print (f)

n = 3
f = [[[0.0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]
f[0][0][0] = 5
print (f)
```

`numpy` Solution:

> Quickstart tutorial: [array-creation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#array-creation)

```
n = 2
f = np.zeros((2, 3,))

n = 3
f = np.zeros((2, 3, 3))
```

> **Output**:
>
> [[8, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]
>      [[[5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]], [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]]]